# Docker build is saying unsatisfiable constraints

Tags: ruby-on-rails, docker, docker-compose

I am trying to setup a docker image that can run a legacy Rails 2.3 application that uses ruby 1.8.7.

I found this dockerfile and when I try and run it, I get the following error:

> fetch
>   http://alpine.gliderlabs.com/alpine/v3.6/main/x86_64/APKINDEX.tar.gz
>   fetch
>   http://alpine.gliderlabs.com/alpine/v3.6/community/x86_64/APKINDEX.tar.gz
>   ERROR: unsatisfiable constraints:   ruby-rmagick (missing):
>       required by: world[ruby-rmagick]   libressl-dev-2.5.5-r2:
>       conflicts:
>                  openssl-dev-1.0.2o-r1[pc:libcrypto=2.5.5]
>                  openssl-dev-1.0.2o-r1[pc:libssl=2.5.5]
>                  openssl-dev-1.0.2o-r1[pc:openssl=2.5.5]
>       satisfies:
>                  mariadb-dev-10.1.32-r0[libressl-dev]   openssl-dev-1.0.2o-r1:
>       conflicts:
>                  libressl-dev-2.5.5-r2[pc:libcrypto=1.0.2o]
>                  libressl-dev-2.5.5-r2[pc:libssl=1.0.2o]
>                  libressl-dev-2.5.5-r2[pc:openssl=1.0.2o]
>       satisfies: world[openssl-dev] ERROR: Service 'rails' failed to build: The command '/bin/sh -c apk update &&     apk upgrade &&
>   apk --no-cache add tzdata     $BUILD_PACKAGES $GEM_PACKAGES &&   cp
>   /usr/share/zoneinfo/Asia/Tokyo /etc/localtime &&   apk del tzdata'
>   returned a non-zero code: 4

The Dockerfile looks like:

```
FROM gliderlabs/alpine:latest

ENV BUILD_PACKAGES bash wget curl tar make gcc alpine-sdk zlib zlib-dev readline 
ENV GEM_PACKAGES openssl openssl-dev libxml2-dev libxslt-dev mysql mariadb-dev imagemagick imagemagick-dev imagemagick-c++ ruby-rmagick

RUN apk update && \
    apk upgrade && \
    apk --no-cache add tzdata \
    $BUILD_PACKAGES $GEM_PACKAGES && \
  cp /usr/share/zoneinfo/Asia/Tokyo /etc/localtime && \
  apk del tzdata 

# build ruby
RUN wget -q -O ruby-1.8.7-p374.tar.gz http://cache.ruby-lang.org/pub/ruby/1.8/ruby-1.8.7-p374.tar.gz && \
    tar -zxvf ruby-1.8.7-p374.tar.gz && \
    rm ruby-1.8.7-p374.tar.gz

WORKDIR ruby-1.8.7-p374
RUN ./configure --with-openssl-dir=/usr/bin
RUN make
RUN make install

# install rubygems
WORKDIR /
RUN wget http://production.cf.rubygems.org/rubygems/rubygems-1.3.7.tgz && \
    tar -zxvf rubygems-1.3.7.tgz && \
    rm rubygems-1.3.7.tgz
WORKDIR rubygems-1.3.7
RUN ruby setup.rb

# install bundler
RUN gem install bundler

WORKDIR /app
COPY Gemfile /app/

# bundle install
RUN bundle install
COPY . /home/app
```